# SQLite: Populating a column based on matching data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

this may be slightly confusing to explain but hopefully it makes sense...

I have a database with 3 tables in total:

- table 1: Col1 has a reference code which is pulled from a file imported daily.
- table 2: Col1 stores a list of reference codes and also a Col2 with a corresponding product code.
- table 3: Is my output table with an empty col:1 to accept the product code from table2: Col2.

I would like to have it read the reference code from table 1: col1, match it to table 2: col1 and then populate table 3: col1 using the corresponding product code from table: 2 col2.

I'm completely new to SQL and things have been going well so far, but this is a bit beyond me, I have tested a few queries which have compared and returned the data but not written it to the table or it has written it to the table but not correctly.

I have been trying to use an update method as table 3 already contains some data, using the 'where' condition sees the two reference codes as being the same, but due to there being multiple tables and columns involved, I'm getting lost with the correct syntax.

Comment: [ask] [mre]
[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Answer (score 1):

To insert new rows in table3:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (col1, other_columns)
SELECT table2.col2, some_other_columns FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.col1 LIKE '%'|table1.col1|'%;
```

If table3 is already populated and you need to update it:

```
UPDATE table3
SET table3.other_column = query.some_other_column
FROM (SELECT table2.col2, some_other_column FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.col1 LIKE '%'|table1.col1|'%' WHERE table3.col1 = table2.col2) AS query
WHERE table3.col1 = query.col2;
```